# jQuery Sticky Header displacing the page content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I am using jQuery Sticky header in my theme. It seems to work fine in most of the pages but in two pages it is displacing the content to the right on load and on scrolling down it places it back in the right position. i am trying to debug the issue with no results.

**On Page Load**
[image]

**On Scroll**
[image]

[DEMO Link](http://play.mink7.com/ftb/contact_us.html)

Comment: IDK..but <div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper" style="height: 50px;">
<nav style="position:fixed"> 
<div class="container">...making nav position fixed solves the problem,is it valid to do?

Comment: In your about page you have `clear: both;` applied on about main div, but not on the contact page..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used "clear:both" on .page

```
.page {
  clear: both;
}
```

The problem is that the #nav is overflowing out of your header and pushes the page to the right side.

Answer (score 4):

Adding this will fix the problem:

```
.page {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: You might notice there's a small "jump" in the content when you start scrolling down. This is due to the "nav" element switching from position:relative to position:fixed. You can "fix" this by adding either `nav { position:absolute; }` or nav `{ float:left; width:100%; }`, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `overflow: hidden` from `.page` at your css

```
.page {
   overflow: visible
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<div style="height: 50px;" class="sticky-wrapper" id="undefined-sticky-wrapper"></div>
<!--- PLEASE INCLUDE  -->
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

put style="clear:both"  after header main div (#undefined-sticky-wrapper)